# About smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, experimental-features, usability

I trade (scalping) cryptocurrency futures on binance. I'm not a developer and I don't know programming languages. Can I learn to write smart contracts without knowing js or java? and advise please , how should i start&

Comment: You can start by reading the solidity documentation : https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes you could by learning the language of Ethereum smart contracts, [Solidity](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/).

In practice, if you don't already know how to code, you will have a hard time understanding Solidity. It has its own quirks and there is not much documentation available. It would be much easier to learn another language first to learn how to code (I would suggest Ruby for its ease of reading and forgiveness of errors).

However, even if you can deploy a smart contract by using Solidity, you will only be able to interact manually with it. If you want a software to automatically call your smart contract, you have to learn other languages like Javascript and the [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/) library.

I learned to code as a hobby 5 years ago and learned Solidity and Javascript about 2 years ago. It can be done if you have the motivation!

Comment: Also, as a good rule of a thumb, it will take at least the minimum of five years to become a programmer that produce anything useful in smart contracts and blockchain industry.